# XML Schema validation using OASIS XML Catalog (Maven or Ant)

Tags: xml, ant, xsd, maven-3, xml-validation

I'm trying to set up a product for our company's XSDs that validates a bunch of XML files against those XSDs.

Our project is maven based, and I use an ant script to generate catalog files (which makes it easier to add all those schemas to an eclipse instance).

The problem I have is that I'm unable to to set up a maven or ant task that validates a bunch of example xml files against those schemas by using the XML catalog. I don't want to explicitly define the URN to XSD rules for all these schemas (that's what I have the XML Catalg for).

I've tried the following setups:

**Maven**

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>validate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <catalogs>
            <catalog>${project.build.outputDirectory}/catalog.xml</catalog>
        </catalogs>
        <validationSets>
            <validationSet>
                <dir>src/test/xml</dir>
                <validating>true</validating>
            </validationSet>
        </validationSets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This fails to parse the catalog.xml. The base catalog.xml contains relative nextCatalog entries, which are not correctly expanded (the absolute path is wrong). When I directly add the 2 catalog.xml entries to the pom, only the first one is parsed.

But even if only the first catalog.xml file is parsed is fails to validate the xml file:

```
 line 4,  column 191: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'mtc:SERVICE_ORDER_MSG'.
```

The example XML file are valid, so apparently maven doesn't link the schemas loaded via the catalog with the validator. With -X I do see it processes the catalog and sees the schemas and their namespaces.

**ANT**

With ant I tried the following set up (tried various suggestions found on the internet):

```
<target name="test">
    <schemavalidate warn="true" failonerror="true" fullchecking="true">
        <fileset dir="src/test/xml">
            <include name="ASN_207a44e3-0aeb6cd8-551ffcc2-2ca1409a.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <xmlcatalog>
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="resolver.jar" />
                <pathelement location="ant-apache-resolver-1.8.4.jar" />
            </classpath>
            <xmlcatalog>
                <catalogpath>
                    <pathelement location="target/classes/MTC/catalog.xml" />
                </catalogpath>
            </xmlcatalog>
        </xmlcatalog>
    </schemavalidate>
</target>
```

In this case I get no indication that the catalog file is parsed. I only get the error of unexpected elements. When I change the ant script to directly use the schema files it works, but that's not the set up I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by creating a validationSet in the maven project for each XSD and with the files to test against in separate folders.

```
<validationSet>
  <dir>src/test/xml/foo</dir>
  <validating>true</validating>
  <systemId>http://example.org/schema/foo.xsd</systemId>
</validationSet>
<validationSet>
  <dir>src/test/xml/bar</dir>
  <validating>true</validating>
  <systemId>http://example.org/schema/bar.xsd</systemId>
</validationSet>
```

The second catalog.xml is apparently read properly.